# How can I obtain correct table of contents order in beamer when including subsections from files?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, include

How can I fix the table of contents order in my beamer?
I work with a main file and include one file for each section. 
However the table of contents puts the subsections **before** their respective section.

mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author[N. Surname]{Name Surname}

\begin{filecontents}{dummyslide}
  \subsection{dummy1}
  \frame{Dummyslide}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}

  \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}

  \section{sec1}
  \include{dummyslide}

\end{document}
```

[image: result (toc slide only)]

Comment: I added a possible workaround as answer but will accept any better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `\include` but `\input`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author[N. Surname]{Name Surname}
\begin{filecontents}{dummyslide}
  \subsection{dummy1}
  \frame{Dummyslide}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
  \section{sec1}
  \input{dummyslide}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to insert the `\section{}` command in the included file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author[N. Surname]{Name Surname}

\begin{filecontents}{dummyslide}
  \section{sec1}
  \subsection{dummy1}
  \frame{Dummyslide}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}

  \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}

  \include{dummyslide}

\end{document}
```

However, it is only a workaround rather than a fix.